# I'm trying to count the percentage of every letter in a document by using a scanner, but I can't figure out how to correctly compute and display it

Tags: java, frequency, alphabet

First I uploaded the file I'm using, the constitution. Then, I created two arrays, one for the length of the alphabet, the second to compute the frequency. I created a while loop to read every line in the document and count the frequency of every letter, I just can't figure out how to compute each as a percentage of each letter because after I'm going to put it into a bar chart.

```
        int [ ]lettersLabels = new int [26];
        int [ ]lettersFrequency = new int [26];
        String line;

//initialize arrays
        letterLabels = 0;
        lettersFrequency = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(constitution);

         while(sc.hasNextLine())
         {
            line = sc.nextLine();
            line = sc.toLowerCase();
            char[] characters = line.toCharArray();
         
            for (int i = 0; i< characters.length ; i++) 
            {
                if((characters[i] >='a') && (characters[i]<='z'))
                {
                     lettersLabels[characters[i] -'a' ]++;
                }
            }
         }
         
         for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) 
         {
          lettersFrequency = 'a' + [characters[i] -'a' ]++;
          lettersFrequency = lettersFrequency / 100;
          System.out.println(lettersFrequency);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Percentage is `ratio * 100` (`1/2 = 0.5 = (0.5 * 100)% = 50%`), and the ratio here is `lettersLabels[i] / totalLetters`. So, in order to find the percentage, you just use `lettersFrequency[i] = (double) lettersLabels[i] / (double) totalLetters * 100;`. So, you might need a variable `totalLetters` at the beginning to count the number of letters.

You have a mistake in your code, which is initializing arrays with `0`. You have already initialized the arrays with `int[] arr = new int[26];`, so you don't need those two lines, which will give an error since initializing arrays with an `int` is the wrong type. Also, when setting some part of `lettersFrequency` to something, you need to specify the index, like `lettersFrequency[i]`, and instead of using `characters` when its out of scope to get the characters, so instead you have to use the `letterLabels` array.

Answer (score 0):

Here I've fix some of the errors with description see the code comments for explanation :

```
        int [ ]lettersLabels = new int [26];
        int [ ]lettersFrequency = new int [26];
        String line;
        
        int totalLetter =0; // needed to calculate %

// No need to initialize, it's already initialized with 0 values.
// remove those lines.
//initialize arrays
//        letterLabels = 0;
//        lettersFrequency = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(constitution);
        
         while(sc.hasNextLine())
         {
            line = sc.nextLine();
            // need to lower case the current line
            line = line.toLowerCase();
            char[] characters = line.toCharArray();
         
            for (int i = 0; i< characters.length ; i++) 
            {
                if((characters[i] >='a') && (characters[i]<='z'))
                {
                     // lets count the letter frequency.
                     totalLetter++;
                     lettersFrequency[characters[i] -'a' ]++;
                }
            }
         }

         // get rid of divide by zero exception
         if(totalLetter ==0) totalLetter =1;
         
         for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) 
         {
          char ch = 'a'+i;
          // let's count the parentage of each letter.
          double parcentage = (lettersFrequency[i]*100.00)/totalLetter;
          System.out.println("parcentage of "+ ch+ " is: " +lettersFrequency +"%");
         }
```